# Is a finitely generated torsion-free R-module free over R if R is an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules, free-modules

I know this is the case if $R$ is a PID, but PID's are special instances of Integral Domains, so I am wondering if there is a counter-example to the case where R is an integral domain.

This post shows the result when $R$ is a Principal Ideal Domain: [Proof about finitely generated torsion-free R-module M is free, where R is a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334863/proof-about-finitely-generated-torsion-free-r-module-m-is-free-where-r-is-a-pid)

Comment: Geometrically, you are asking if all line bundles over an (irreducible) affine variety are trivial. The simplest counterexample is to take the line bundle $L(P - Q)$ on an elliptic curve, punctured at the origin, where $P$ and $Q$ are distinct points not equal to the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, which is not a principal ideal domain, for example
the ring of integers in a number field such as $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$.
Then $R$ will have a non-principal ideal, $I$ say. Then, as an $R$-module, $I$ is finitely generated,
torsion free, but not principal. In the above example, we could take $I=2R+\sqrt{-6}R$.